# Need to Create a Query in Access 2010 that is a front end for SQL Server 2008 backend

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, ms-access

Access 2010 Query Builder

I need a query or expression in a query criteria to show only `OrderID`'s where **all** `SampleID`'s in that order have a `ResultStatus` of 3

```
OrderID    SampleNumber    ResultStatus     Test
-------------------------------------------------
171178      171178-01      3              PH
171178      171178-01      3              Salt
171178      171178-01      0              HM
171300      171300-02      3              Salt
171308      171308-01      3              PH
171308      171308-01      3              HM
```

- OrderID - 171178 Should not Show because SampleID 171178-01 Test HM has a ResultStatus of 0
- OrderID - 171300 Should Show
- OrderID - 1713088 Should Show

I have searched the web for days but can't seem to state it in a way that gets results. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is want I finally came up with that works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.CustomerName
                , SampleDetails.OrderID
                , SampleDetails.SampleNumber
                , Orders.DefaultReceiveDate
                , SampleDetails.Matrix
                , SampleDetails.Test
                , SampleDetails.Method
                , SampleDetails.CustomerTestPrice
                , Results.ResultStatus
  FROM Results
       INNER JOIN (((SampleDetails
                     LEFT JOIN Invoices
                            ON SampleDetails.OrderID = Invoices.OrderID)
                    INNER JOIN Orders
                            ON SampleDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID)
                   INNER JOIN Customers
                           ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID)
               ON Results.OrderID = SampleDetails.OrderID
 GROUP BY Customers.CustomerName
          , SampleDetails.OrderID
          , SampleDetails.SampleNumber
          , Orders.DefaultReceiveDate
          , SampleDetails.Matrix
          , SampleDetails.Test
          , SampleDetails.Method
          , Results.ResultStatus
          , SampleDetails.CustomerTestPrice
          , Invoices.InvoiceID
          , Results.ApprovedDate
          , Orders.CustomerID
          , SampleDetails.Cancelled
HAVING ( ( ( Orders.DefaultReceiveDate ) > [Enter the start date:] )
         AND ( ( Invoices.InvoiceID ) IS NULL )
         AND ( ( Results.ApprovedDate ) IS NOT NULL )
         AND ( ( Orders.CustomerID ) IS NOT NULL
               AND ( Orders.CustomerID ) NOT LIKE "AFL*" )
         AND ( ( SampleDetails.Cancelled ) = False )
         AND ( SUM(IIF([ResultStatus] = 3, 0, 1)) ) = 0 )
 ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

Comment: AFL Uninvoiced - All Approved Query 5
SELECT DISTINCTROW [AFL Uninvoiced - All Approved].CustomerName, [AFL Uninvoiced - All Approved].OrderID, [AFL Uninvoiced - All Approved].SampleNumber, [AFL Uninvoiced - All Approved].DefaultReceiveDate, [AFL Uninvoiced - All Approved].Test, [AFL Uninvoiced - All Approved].Method, [AFL Uninvoiced - All Approved].ResultStatus, [AFL Uninvoiced - All Approved].CustomerTestPrice
FROM [AFL Uninvoiced - All Approved View] INNER JOIN [AFL Uninvoiced - All Approved] ON [AFL Uninvoiced - All Approved View].OrderID = [AFL Uninvoiced - All Approved].OrderID;

Comment: and finally the view: SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.DefaultReceiveDate, Orders.CustomerID
FROM Orders INNER JOIN Results ON Orders.OrderID = Results.OrderID
WHERE ((Orders.CustomerID) Is Not Null And (Orders.CustomerID) Not Like "AFL*")
AND (Orders.DefaultReceiveDate)>[Enter the start date:]
GROUP BY Orders.OrderID, Orders.DefaultReceiveDate, Orders.CustomerID
HAVING Sum(IIf(Results.[ResultStatus]=3,0,1))=0;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that ResultStatus cannot be null and that the table is called Orders, you could say:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.SampleNumber, Orders.ResultStatus, Orders.Test
FROM Orders
WHERE Orders.OrderID Not In (SELECT OrderId FROM Orders WHERE ResultStatus <> 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your answer was able to give me all the OdreID that had 3s in Results. I'm sure I didn't state it right but what I was after was only the OrderIDs that had 3s in every sampleID and not display the orders that did not so if a sample in that orderID had a 2 or 1 in ResultStatus it would not diplay the entire order.